# Create a new column in pandas dataframe using column and its value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame

```
 df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4],
                    'attr1':[1,1,0,0],
                    'attr2':[0,1,1,0],
                    'attr3':[1,1,1,0],
                    'attr4':[1,1,1,1]})
```

[image]

I want to convert it to

[image]

Basically create a new variable which will contain previous dataframe columns if its value is 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
df1 = df.filter(like='attr')
df = df.drop(df1.columns, axis=1)
df['var'] = df1.dot(df1.columns + ' ').str.rstrip()
print (df)
   id                      var
0   1        attr1 attr3 attr4
1   2  attr1 attr2 attr3 attr4
2   3        attr2 attr3 attr4
3   4                    attr4
```

**Explanation**:

1. Filter columns by [`filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) - only attribute columns
2. Remove columns by [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html)
3. Matrix multiplication by columns with [`DataFrame.dot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html)
4. Last remove last whitespaces by [`rstrip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.rstrip.html)

Alternative solution:

```
cols = df.columns[df.columns.str.startswith('attr')]
df = df.drop(cols, axis=1).assign(var=df[cols].dot(cols + ' ').str.rstrip())
print (df)
   id                      var
0   1        attr1 attr3 attr4
1   2  attr1 attr2 attr3 attr4
2   3        attr2 attr3 attr4
3   4                    attr4
```

For revert back use [`str.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html):

```
df1 = df.join(df.pop('var').str.get_dummies(' '))
print (df1)
   id  attr1  attr2  attr3  attr4
0   1      1      0      1      1
1   2      1      1      1      1
2   3      0      1      1      1
3   4      0      0      0      1
```

Comment: Thank you for prompt response! How can  I revert back to original data frame using newly created data frame?